# Integration by parts sine

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity, pi, integration-by-parts

Let $f(t)$ be a continuous function.

so-$$\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin x)dx$$
 I tried many times Integration in parts but didn't succeed.

Comment: $$I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$$

Answer (score 3):

By the change of variable $u=\pi-x$, one has
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-u)f(\sin (\pi-u))du=\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin u)du-\int_{0}^{\pi}\!uf(\sin u)du
$$ using $\sin (\pi-u)=\sin u$.

Comment: @YardenSharabi You are very welcome.

Comment: maybe would gain to explicit the double inversion $\int_{\pi}^0(-du)=\int_0^{\pi}du$.